# Show that $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a+b,b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

Show that $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a+b,b)$

I understand the proof up till this point:

By definition of $\gcd(a,b)$ it implies that $d|a$ and $d\mid b$ thus, $d\mid a+b$, a linear combination of the two.

By definition of $\gcd(a+b,b)$ it implies that $d\mid a+b$ and $d\mid b$ thus, $d\mid(a+b)-b = a +b - b  =b$

In the second statement, I don't understand where the subtraction comes from in $d\mid(a+b)-b = a +b - b  =b$

Comment: The mistake is that $(a+b)-b = a$, not $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first statement,it should be like that:

Let $d=gcd(a,b)$

By definition, $d \mid a$, $d \mid b$,so $d$ divides also any linear combination of $a,b$,so it divides also their sum $a+b$.

In the second statement:

Let $d=gcd(a+b,b)$.

By definition, $d \mid a+b \text{ and } d \mid b$,so $d$ divides also any linear combination of $a+b,b$,so it divides also their difference $a+b-b=a$.

Comment: So i could say its (a+b) + b OR (a+b) - b for the combinations it divides?

Comment: Yes,it divides any linear combination,it divides for example also $4(a+b)-3b$.But,in your case,to show what you want to,you take the difference of $a+b$ and $b$.